# How to match names and email addresses in a list of names and a list of email addresses?

Tags: python, email, fuzzy-search

Given a few human names and a few emails (the number of names is no less than the number of emails), I want to match the names with the emails. I assume for each name there is at most one email be his/her true mail, and each email must be a true email of one and only one of the given persons.

For example, given the names John Smith, Jennifer Lopez, Michael Jordan, and the emails, johns@email.com, jlopez@xyz.com. I'd like to associate John Smith with johns@email.com, Jennifer Lopez with jlopez@xyz.com, and Michael Jordan with nothing.

Note that an email of a person can be somewhat related to the name but the match can be very fuzzy. For example, John Smith may have any of the following email addresses.

- jsmith@email.com
- johns@email.com
- johnsmith@email.com
- john.smith@email.com
- smithjohn@email.com
- smithj@email.com
- sjohn@email.com
- johnsmith000@email.com

It seems one will need to code several rules for deciphering email addresses and the human names to perform fuzzy matching. Does anybody have any example code on how this should be done in python?

Comment: This isn't a good question for Stack Overflow. Have you tried anything yet? If so, include it, and the output.

Comment: When you say there can be only one such name in email list, what do you mean? Do you mean johnsmith000@email.com isn't a valid one?

Comment: I mean only one of these emails is the true email of John Smith. I.e., if some email other than johnsmith000@email.com is the email of John Smith, johnsmith000@email.com must not be his email.

Answer (score 0):

I aggree wiht bjkistad, there are probably better places to ask this question, but with that being said a naive implementation would be to use the [Levenshtein Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

I leave the implementation of the Levenshtein Difference function as an exercise for the student...(You can find many implementations on the internet.

```
def levenshtein(a, b):
    pass

human_name = 'John Smith'
addresses = ['jsmith@email.com', 'johns@email.com',
             'johnsmith@email.com', 'john.smith@email.com',
             'smithjohn@email.com', 'smithj@email.com',
             'sjohn@email.com', 'johnsmith000@email.com']
name_parts = [address.split('@')[0] for address in addresses]
lev_diff = [levenshtein(ename, human_name) for ename in name_parts]
index, score = min(enumerate(lev_name), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
best_match addresses[index]

print "The best match %s has the score %d" % (best_match, score)

#OUTPUT:
# The best match johnsmith@email.com has the score 3
```

As I stated this is an extremely naive version off the top of my head, there are better pattern matching algorithms and libraries...Just ask the Google.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. All the example emails should be legitimate emails for John Smith, there is no need to call levenshtein to decide which is the best. What I need is to distinguish the emails shown in the original question with emails from others like aquil.abdullah@email.com. Would you recommend a better place to ask this question.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. There is no way to know which email address belongs to "the" John Smith that you are interested in if all of the email addresses that you are searching are valid unless you already know which email address belongs to "the" John Smith you are interested in. I think you need to edit your question and provide a bette example of inputs and outputs.